# MSSQL Trigger Update on column

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I have 2 tables and I want table 1 to have a trigger that insert or update in table 2, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DevicePorts](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IsInUse] [bit] NOT NULL,
)
```

Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DevicePortActivities](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [EndTime] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [FK_DevicePortID] [int] NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES DevicePorts(ID),
)
```

Start of my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PortInUse
   ON  DevicePorts
   AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF UPDATE (IsInUse) 
    BEGIN
        IF IsInUse = 1
        THEN
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[DevicePortActivities]
            (
                [ID]
                ,[StartTime]
                ,[EndTime]
                ,[FK_DevicePortID]
            )
            VALUES
            (
                NEWID(),
                SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),
                null,
                <DevicePortID>
            )
        ELSE 
            UPDATE [dbo].[DevicePortActivities]
            SET EndTime = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
            WHERE FK_DevicePortID = <DevicePortID> AND EndTime is null
        END
    END 
END
GO
```

What I'm trying to do is when 'IsInUse' is modified it should insert a row into 'DevicePortActivities' or update.

Conditions are, if 'IsInUse' is true then it should insert a record, if it's false it should update the last record where 'EndTime' is null.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to treat `inserted` as a *table*. I'd suggest looking at [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for this (because different rows may have had different changes applied by a single `UPDATE`).

Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PortInUse
   ON  DevicePorts
   AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    MERGE INTO [dbo].[DevicePortActivities] t
    USING (select i.ID,i.IsInUse as NewUse,d.IsInUse as OldUse
        from inserted i inner join deleted d on i.ID = d.ID) s
    ON
        t.FK_DevicePortID = s.ID
    WHEN MATCHED AND t.EndTime is null AND NewUse = 0 and OldUse = 1
    THEN UPDATE SET EndTime = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
    WHEN NOT MATCHED AND NewUse = 1 and OldUse = 0
    THEN INSERT ([ID]
                ,[StartTime]
                ,[EndTime]
                ,[FK_DevicePortID])
         VALUES (NEWID(),
                SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),
                null,
                s.ID);
END
```

Comment: Thank you so much, never heard about "MERGE" - but i will definitely look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my question

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[PortInUse]
   ON  [dbo].[DevicePorts]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF UPDATE (IsInUse) 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @IsInUse bit;
        DECLARE @PortID int;
        SELECT @IsInUse = i.IsInUse FROM inserted i; 
        SELECT @PortID = i.ID FROM inserted i; 
        IF (@IsInUse = 1)
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[DevicePortActivities]
            (
                [ID]
                ,[StartTime]
                ,[EndTime]
                ,[FK_DevicePortID]
            )
            VALUES
            (
                NEWID(),
                SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),
                null,
                @PortID
            );
        ELSE 
            UPDATE [dbo].[DevicePortActivities]
            SET EndTime = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
            WHERE FK_DevicePortID = @PortID AND EndTime is null;
    END 
END
```

I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this, but it's working.

Comment: ""working", but not really. `inserted` can contain *0*, 1 or *many* rows (depending on how many rows were affected by the update). You arbitrarily obtain values from this mix of data and place them in scalar variables. *You're not even guaranteed that you get consistent values of `IsInUse` and `ID` from the same row*. You need to write code that treats `inserted` properly *as a table*. I'd suggest you look at `MERGE`.